# Can a Shared Script be Hidden from the User the Script is Shared With?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Is it possible to deploy some scripts (along with triggers) for sheets, docs, forms of a customer in a way that their implementation remains hidden?

If customer shares his sheet so I can put some code into script editor - it asks for access to all of my google docs. I can set up special account for such purposes but, but it's not seamless.

Comment: Possible alternative: to establish a new g-account and let my customer share his spreadsheet where I can store the script.

Customer cannot see my documents as I have nothing there, but still I cannot protect the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to keep ***some*** of your script hidden.  The issue is; who's account does anything run under.  You could share some script with someone that ran an HTTP Request with `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` to your Apps Script Content Service script.  So, you would have a Stand Alone Apps Script in your Drive, in your account that received a request, and returned something.  That could cause lots of requests to the script in your account, depending on how many people you are sharing this with.  The code that the user had in their file, would access their files, and work on their files, and the user could see that code.  Your Content Service would basically just be processing data and accessing files that aren't in the users account.  Anything that had to do with the User Interface you couldn't hide from the user.  You can't hide values being copied into cells, or formatting the color, or opening a dialog box.  You could use your content service to do things like create the HTML, then return the HTML to the user.  That way the user wouldn't be able to see the code that did something like create dynamic HTML.